# dynamically changing PHP value with dropdown select using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a drop down box like:

```
<select class="form-control" id="travelid" name="travelreport">
```

with javascript:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#travelid").on('click', function(){            
        var v = $('#travelid').find('option:selected').val();
        $.get("includes/settravelid.php", { param1: v } );

        });
    });

    </script>
```

to get the value of the selected item from the dropdown  box, send it to my PHP file:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$value = isset($_GET['param1']) ? $_GET['param1'] : '';

$_SESSION['travelReportID'] = $value;

 ?>
```

where I can set the value $travelReportID = $_SESSION['travelReportID']; to dynamically change a query based on the selected item from the drop down box, but it isn't quite working.  Any ideas?  It seems to be working but is not refreshing the page when I select something...

Comment: why should it refresh the page?

Comment: The whole point of AJAX is that it doesn't reload the page. If you want to change something as a result, you should echo something in the PHP script, and the callback function of `$.get` can use that response to make changes to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use on change function in that case

```
<script>

    $(document).on('change',"#travelid", function(){            
    var v = $(this).val();
    $.get("includes/settravelid.php", { param1: v } );

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `.delegate()`, use `.on()`.

Comment: changed delegate() to on()

Comment: delegate was old function and depreciated

Comment: How would I change the above code then to dynamically change my MySQL query and have the page information refresh?  I am using    $_SESSION['travelReportID'] to set the value for:

    $travelReportID = $_SESSION['travelReportID'];

    if ($travelReportID) {

 $sql  = "SELECT * FROM tblExpenses WHERE travelReportID =     $travelReportID ORDER BY travelReportID DESC LIMIT $page_1, $per_page";

    } else {

 $sql  = "SELECT * FROM tblExpenses ORDER BY travelReportID DESC LIMIT $page_1, $per_page";

    }

Comment: use this code into your javascript code and your backend logic does not have issue to update variable.

Comment: true but I wanted it updated when I selected and not have to have a submit button

Comment: yes , on change on #ID when value change , and send its value on backend

Comment: I do not know how to that, that is what I am asking, do you have code to show it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reload the page,you can use the callback function of $.get. eg: {window.location.reload()}